# How to print using recursive in C?

Tags: c, recursion

I wanna print `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256` out on screen. But all I got is `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void print(int n) {
  if(n<=8) {
    printf(" %d ",pow(2,n));
    return print(n+1);
  }
}

int main() {
  print(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type is the return value of `pow`? What type can you print with `%d`?

Comment: `printf(" %d ",pow(2,n));` --> `printf(" %d ", (int)pow(2,n));`. Also `return print(n+1);` --> `print(n+1);`

Comment: Any good reason to use recursion here?

Comment: Double has "%f" pattern not "%d". In some compiler is lf, for sure not "%d". Otherwise cast to int (int)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Almost certainly the recursion is an exercise in working recursively so "yes", but in the absence of an exercise, the answer would be "no".

Comment: I wounder that this actually compiles. A `void` function does not `return` anything. And for integers use ineger operations. Don't mix with floating point (and here it is absolutely not necessary anyway).

Answer (score 8):

[`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is a *floating point* function. It returns a `double`. Which you can't print with `"%d"` (using mismatching format and argument is *undefined behavior*).

Either use the correct format (e.g. `"%f"`) or cast the result to an `int`. Or why not simply use binary arithmetic with shifting the value `1` the correct number of bits.

Answer (score 7):

`pow` returns a `double`, the `%d` format specifier expects an `int`.

Try updating your `printf` call to use `%.0f`, or cast the result of `pow` to be an `int` instead:

Option 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print(int n)
{
    if(n<=8)
    {
        printf("%.0f\n", pow(2, n));
        return print(n+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    print(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print(int n)
{
    if(n<=8)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (int) pow(2, n));
        return print(n+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    print(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using `return print(n+1)` given that the return type for `print` is `void`. You could rewrite `print` to be a function that returns the power of two of `n` and then access the return value from `main` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int print(int n)
{
    return (int) pow(2, n);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        printf("%d\n", print(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have `return value` in a function returning void, even if the value from the function is void.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agreed; it just happened to work on my compiler (MSVC) though it did throw a warning about that.

Comment: @GovindParmar: Which MSVC version? 10?

Comment: @alk The one that ships with VS2015... `cl /?` returns 19.00.24215.1

Comment: @GovindParmar: Are you sure this very version didn't issue a warning about the mismatch between the conversion specifier and argument used in the printf call?

Comment: @alk No it did not.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1x26e0x.aspx, particularly the second bullet point at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

The solution I post here is able to generate sequences such that you require using: a start value (the x variable), a factor value (the v variable) and a number of terms value (the n variable)

The case you are asking for (1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256) is when `x=1; v=2; n=9;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int x, int v, int n)
{
        printf("%d ",x);
        if (--n)
                print(x*v,v,n);

        return;
}

int main(void)
{
        print(1,2,9);puts("");
        return 0;
}
```